# AJAX - Siempre devuelve error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo este código mediante jQuery y AJAX hago una llamada a una API mia propia donde hago un put, la llamada la hace bien porque si hago "debug" en el controlador veo como los datos llegan y se guardan bien en la BBDD, además la api devuelve un status = 200.

EL problema lo tengo en el código AJAX donde todo el rato me "entra" a la función error.

```
 <script>
    $("#btn-save-user").click(function() {

        var email =  $('#email').val();

        $('#alert-ok').css('display', 'none');
        $('#error-list').css('display', 'none');


        $.ajax({
            url : '/api/users/' + user_id ,
            data : { email : email },
            type : 'PUT',
            dataType : 'json',
            success:function(data){
                alert('success');
                alert(data);

                $("#alert-ok").empty();
                $('#alert-ok').css('display', '');
                $("#alert-ok" ).append('<ul>· ' + data + '</ul>');

                $('.btn-submit').prop('disabled', false);
            },
            error:function (data) {

                alert('error');
                console.log(data);

                $("#error-list").empty();
                $('#error-list').css('display', '');

                $.each( data.responseJSON.errors , function( i, val ) {
                    $( "#error-list" ).append('<ul>· ' + val + '</ul>');
                });

                $('.btn-submit').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Como podeis ver este es un console.log(data) en la función error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema viene dado porque en la petición declaras la propiedad `dataType`con el valor `'json'`. Esto hace que jQuery intente procesar la respuesta como si fuera JSON, pero como no puede, falla.

Es decir, jQuery intenta lo siguiente:

```js
const response = {
responseText : `

Usuario creado correctamente`
};

console.log(response);

try {
  JSON.parse(response.responseText)
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error',e.toString());
}
```

Soluciones:

1. Haz que la respuesta del servidor sea un JSON válido:

   ```
   { data: "Usuario creado correctamente" }
   ```
2. Cambia el dataType para aceptar texto plano: `dataType : "text"`

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso. 1000 gracias !!!!